# Populating list with values

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, for-loop

I have a list called  **deck** with 16 items in it:

```
deck = range(0,8)*2
```

I need to create a list that has the same number of entries as the **deck** list, but initially, they're all set to **False**

Say the name of the new list is **new_list**

How do I create this list without typing **False** 16 times? When I try this, I get index out of range error.

```
deck = range(0,8)*2
new_list = []
for card in deck:
    new_list[card] = False
```

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

You can repeat a list multiple times by multiplying it. For example, this will solve your problem:

```
>>> [False] * 16
[False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False]
```

You can also do this with multiple elements in a list, like so:

```
>>> [1, 2] * 5
[1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2]
```

If you wanted to ensure that the list would expand as you changed the size of the deck, you could multiply by the length, like this:

```
deck = range(0, 8) * 2
falses = [False] * len(deck)
```

You can read the documentation about the list operations [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-str-unicode-list-tuple-bytearray-buffer-xrange) - they're quite handy for situations like this!

Comment: This is a neat solution, but beware that for "complex" types, the resulting list will have `n` copies of the *same* object, rather than `n-1` copies added to the list.

Answer (score 2):

Just to clarify why you get an `IndexError`:

When you create the `new_list` variable, it has a length of 0 and you try to access the the first element, which does not exists.

So in order to let the list grow as you need it you could use the `append` method. Then your code should look something like this:

```
deck = range(0,8)*2
new_list = []
for card in deck:
    new_list.append(False)
```

Comment: 10 seconds faster than me... Good to explain it. It is always good to know what went wrong.